# Console Output in pipeline:Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have created a complex pipeline. In each stage I have called a job. I want to see the console output for each job in a stage in Jenkins. How to get it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The object returned from a build step can be used to query the log like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {

                echo 'Building anotherJob and getting the log'

                script {
                    def bRun = build 'anotherJob' 
                    echo 'last 100 lines of BuildB'
                    for(String line : bRun.getRawBuild().getLog(100)){
                        echo line
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The object returned from the build step is a [RunWrapper](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java) class object. The getRawBuild() call is returning a [Run](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Run.java) object - there may be other options than reading the log line-by-line from the looks of this class. For this to work you need to either disable the pipeline sandbox or get script approvals for these methods:

```
method hudson.model.Run getLog int
method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild
```

If you are doing this for many builds, it would be worth putting some code in a pipeline shared library to do what you need or define a function in the pipeline.