# Make build UNSTABLE if text found in console log using jenkinsfile (jenkins pipeline)

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to login into an instance and check if the file `test.txt` is not empty, then `echo ..` make build unstable using the jenkins pipeline (jenkinsfile)But that's not working.
I have this:

```
post {
        always {
          sh "ssh ubuntu@$Ip 'if [ -s test.txt ] ; then echo some text && cat test.txt'"
        currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
          }
        }
```

Instead of doing above, can I parse through the console log of the latest build to find something eg: `some text` and if that's found I want to make the build unstable

Comment: This shows how to get the console log output in pipeline. Hope it could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510489/console-output-in-pipelinejenkins

Answer (score 0):

You need to return standard out from the script:

```
String stdOut = sh returnStdout: true, script: "ssh ubuntu@$Ip 'if [ -s test.txt ] ; then echo some text && cat test.txt'"

if (stdOut == "") {
   currentBuild.status = 'UNSTABLE'
}
```

Or, you could use `returnStatus` to return the exit code of the script. The documentation for the `sh` step can be found [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The above code is giving me this error: `bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file ERROR: script returned exit code 1`

Comment: It worked when I have `"ssh ubuntu@ip 'if [ -s test.txt ] ;then echo some text; fi '"` , but when I have the test of the code attached (the `String stdout....` stuff, it is not doing anything